# Array not updated when iterating with "let element of array"

Tags: javascript

I fail to see why the first code below(titleCase1) does not capitalize every word, while the second one does(titleCase2).

```js
var result1 = titleCase1('this is a new question in stackoverflow');
console.log('result1:',result1);

var result2 = titleCase2('this is a new question in stackoverflow');
console.log('result2:',result2);

function titleCase1(str) {
    let words = str.split(" ");
      for (let word of words) {
        word = word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
      }
      return words.join(" ");
    }

function titleCase2(str) {
      let words = str.split(" ");
      for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        words[i] = words[i][0].toUpperCase() + words[i].slice(1);
      }
      return words.join(" ");
    }
```

It seems that in the first case the `words` array is not updated and it has something to do with the `let element of array` iterator, but I do not understand why it does not work.

Comment: In the first example, changing the value of `word` doesn't alter the array `words`. In the second one, you are directly changing values of the array `words`.

Answer (score 1):

> Strings, unlike arrays in JavaScript are value objects, not reference objects.

Here:

```
for (let word of words) {
    word = word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
}
```

You are declaring a word variable using `let` and it is scoped to the for loop. This variable is a copy of the substrings in your string. You reassign it at each iteration, but since it is a copy and not a reference to the substrings, your substring in the array `words` doesn't change, only the copy does.

However here:

```
for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    words[i] = words[i][0].toUpperCase() + words[i].slice(1);
}
```

You are changing the substring directly since you update each character by indexing them in the substring array.

Here is a much shorter way to do it with `String.replace`, a regex and an arrow function:

```js
const titleCase = str => str.replace(/(?<=(\s+|^))\w/gi, x => x.toUpperCase());

console.log(titleCase('hello world'));
console.log(titleCase('   hello    world'));
```

The regex `(?<=(\s+|^))` is a positive lookbehind and makes sure that the pattern `\w` (word character) is preceeded by spaces or is located at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 0):

In the first code, you're reassigning a variable. Reassigning a variable, by itself, will never have any effect on anything else, at least in 99% of situations; it'll just mean that further references to `word` inside that `for` block will refer to the new value, rather than the old value. So, your `word = ...` won't affect anything, since you're not doing anything with that new `word` variable name later in the block. (after that iteration ends, the value stored in it will be unreferenced, and will soon be GC'd)

In the second code, you're *mutating an object*: `words[i] =` will mean that further accesses to index `i` of `words` will return the new value.

Answer (score 0):

word is not an array. It is just a word. and you are returning words with joining them which is already a string with no space join will have no effect

```js
function titleCase(str) {
let a=[];
let words = str.split("");
  for (let word of words) {
  
    a.push(word.toUpperCase());
  }
  return a.join("");
}
console.log(titleCase("hello"))
```